# Did someone know this kind of slider?

Tags: wordpress, slider, responsive

I'm converting Adobe XD file to Wordpress and I want to create HTML carousel like this

https://drive.google.com/open?id=13KVinHBsVdolSrqVjlb5KQ9DG-qH8ZmH

I tried owl carousel and something other but none of them worked for me.
If someone knows this type of slider please tell me

Comment: No body know this?!

Comment: @Saveen Do you anything about my problem?